# What is the meaning of '$' in build.gradle script

Tags: gradle, build, native

I am reading documentation about native builds. And there is a following example for building all variants.

```
model {
    tasks {
        buildAllExecutables(Task) {
            dependsOn $.binaries.findAll { it.buildable }
        }
    }
}
```

[Link to documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html#sec:building_all_possible_variants)

What is the meaning of this dollar sign before binaries container?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `$.` notation is a way to reference other elements of the model. By "the model" I mean all the stuff you see when you run `gradle model`. So when we do `$.binaries` we are telling Gradle to go searching for a model element named "binaries". As another example, I could use `$.tasks.foo` to reference the task named "foo".

See [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/software_model.html#dsl-rule-input-dependencies) for more details.